# How do I send a dataframe table using Microsoft Bot Framework (Python)?

Tags: botframework, schema

My goal is to send a dataframe table to the user via Microsoft Bot framework for python.

I tried different methods to send a dataframe using the MessageFactory text and attachment methods. I even tried converting the dataframe object into an image and then send the base64 mime. This worked, however the image was very magnified, and cannot be clicked to view, making most parts of the table unreadable.
I read there are ways to define your own schema (xml/markdown) for tables, but could not find any appropriate resources on how to use them. Do let me know of any way possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use adaptive card table format to show the data